# How to define a type for object with dynamic keys?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define a category type for object with dynamic keys and I think I succeeded in that but don't really know how to assign them in Array.

category.ts

```
interface CategoryType {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

interface Category extends CategoryType {
  [x: string]: {};
}

export const Categories: Record<string, Category> = {
  action: { name: "Action", color: "#f44336" },
  animation: { name: "Animation", color: "#dcf836" },
  adventure: { name: "Adventure", color: "#233a50" },
  //...
};
```

slider.tsx

```
import { Categories } from "@lib/types/category";

export type SliderProps = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  categories: typeof Categories;
  poster: string;
};

const slides: Readonly<SliderProps[]> = [
  {
    id: "1149",
    title: "Blade Runner 2049",
  // I want to be able to add multiple categories for each movie
    categories: [Categories.Action, Categories.Animation],
  },
  //...
];
```

How can I assign the imported Categories into the categories property?

Edit:
The error I had before:

```
(property) categories: Record<string, Category>
Type 'Category[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, Category>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Category[]'.ts(2322)
slider.tsx(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'categories' which is declared here on type 'SliderProps'
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I updated the post with the error msg I was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

categories type should be `Category[]`

```
export type SliderProps = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  categories: Category[];
  poster?: string;
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jnpzah?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 2):

The type should simply be `Category[]`.

```
export type SliderProps = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  categories: Category[];
  poster: string;
};
```

Comment: Still got an error, I edited the post with the error msg.